# Twitter-Post-Fetcher with Jquery (and possibly Vue.js)

Tags: jquery, twitter, vue.js

I'm using [Twitter-Post-Fetcher](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher), to fetch the latest five tweets. So, if I do this:

```
var latestTweets = {
    "id": '695269278174572544',
    "domId": 'latest_tweets',
    "maxTweets": 5,
    "showTime": false,
    "enableLinks": true,
    "showInteraction": false,
    "showUser": false
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(latestTweets);
```

I get the latest 5 tweets. Only the tweets themselves, as intended. Now, how can display them one by one, with a fade in/out effect? I'm able to do that to a hard-coded `unorderd list` with Jquery. Like this (Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/FWZKF/36/)):

```
<div id="latest-tweets">
    <ul>
        <li>pseudo-tweet1</li>
        <li>pseudo-tweet2</li>
        <li>pseudo-tweet3</li>
        <li>pseudo-tweet4</li>
        <li>pseudo-tweet5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 1000;
    $('ul > li').each(function() {
        $(this).show().delay(delay).fadeToggle(2000);
        $(this).hide().fadeToggle(1000);
       delay += 3000;
    });
});
```

The above code renders each one of the list items visible/invible in a paced fashion, as intended.

However, how do I insert real data, more specifically, how do I insert the results from the Twitter-Post-Fetcher call above?

I tried adding Vue.js to the mix, with weird results, such as [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/sfgry1ek/15/), [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/sfgry1ek/16/) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/sfgry1ek/18/).

I'm of course open to entirely different solutions to the problem, which can be  reformulated as: *how to display a list of nth tweets, one at a time?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Vue solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/sfgry1ek/32/

You need to use the `customCallback` to tell twitterFetcher what to do with the tweets.  Then you use `v-for` to repeat the `li` elements for each of the tweets.  You set `transition="fade"` on the elements as well, which causes them to animate when you show/hide them.  Then just a bit of timing logic to show them at the right times.

**html**

```
<div id="latest-tweets">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="tweet in tweets" transition="fade" v-show="showing == $index">{{{ tweet }}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#latest-tweets',
  data: function(){
    return {
      tweets: [],
      showing: 0
    };
  },
  methods:{
    fetch:function(){
        var LatestTweets = {
            "id": '695269278174572544',
            "maxTweets": 5,
            "showTime": false,
            "enableLinks": true,
            "customCallback":this.setTweets,
            "showInteraction": false,
            "showUser": false
            };
      twitterFetcher.fetch(LatestTweets);
    },
    setTweets(tweets){
        this.tweets = tweets;
    },
    rotate: function(){
      if(this.showing == this.tweets.length - 1){
        this.showing = -1;
      }
      this.showing += .5;
      setTimeout(function(){
        this.showing += .5;
      }.bind(this), 600);
    }
  },
  ready:function() {
    this.fetch();
    setInterval(this.rotate, 6000);
  }
});
```

**css**

```
.fade-transition {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Edit: removed the JS `fade` implementation in favor of the CSS one

Comment: Ohh, thanks! That's absolutely great code. I'll have a lot to chew on in the next couple of hours. :-)

Comment: @pierrebonbon I updated the code to handle the transition with CSS instead of JS. easier that way.

Comment: There's one thing I quite don't get in terms of behavior. Why after the last available tweet is displayed for the first time, the interval is somewhat reversed, that is, the time between tweets becomes 6000ms and the time each one of them is displayed becomes 1000ms? Have been trying to figure out for the last few hours and still don't get it why the loop behaves differently after the first iteration.

Comment: @pierrebonbon ah sorry about that.  The way I did the timing was a little hacky because you need a pause in between hiding a tweet and showing the next one.  Thats why I didn't increment `showing` by 1, but rather by `.5` and then `.5` again half a second later.  Looks like during round 2 it was stuck in between so it was going from `1.5` to `2.5` and only stopping at 2 for half a second.  Here's an update: https://jsfiddle.net/sfgry1ek/32/

Comment: No wonder I couldn't get it! That's the part of the code that I still didn't understand entirely. Anyway, thank you so much for your help!