# Vue.js "track-by $index", how to render list items individually

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Until recently I was using `v-show` to display each element in an array, one at a time, in my Vue instance. My html had the following line: `<li v-for="tweet in tweets" v-show="showing == $index">{{{ tweet }}}</li>"`. My root Vue instance was constructed this way (thanks [@Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35544438/4782740)!):

```
new Vue({
    el: '#latest-tweets',
    data: function(){
        return {
            tweets: [],
            showing: 0
        };
    },
    methods:{
        fetch:function(){
            var LatestTweets = {
                "id": '706642968506146818',
                "maxTweets": 5,
                "showTime": false,
                "enableLinks": true,
                "customCallback":this.setTweets,
                "showInteraction": false,
                "showUser": false
            };
            twitterFetcher.fetch(LatestTweets);
        },
        setTweets: function(tweets){
            this.tweets = tweets;
            console.log(tweets);
        },
        rotate: function(){
            if(this.showing == this.tweets.length - 1){
                this.showing = -1;
            }
            this.showing += .5;
            setTimeout(function(){
                this.showing += .5;
            }.bind(this), 1000);
        }
    },
    ready:function() {
        this.fetch();
        setInterval(this.rotate, 10000);
}
```

It was all good until I came accross duplicate values. In order to handle these, I replaced `v-show` with `track-by $index`, as specified [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#track-by-index). I now have this on my html: `<li v-for="tweet in tweets" track-by="$index">{{{ tweet }}}</li>`. The problem is that, instead of rendering each list item individually, the whole list is rendered at once.

As to the above `rotate` method, since I cannot do `track-by="showing == $index"`, it is now useless. As far as I understand, this is due to Vue not being able to detect changes in the length of the Array. There seems to be a workaround, as detailed [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats), which is to "replace items with an empty array instead", which I did at no avail. I cannot figure out what am I missing.

Here're a couple of JsFiddles, with [`v-show`](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/sfgry1ek/43/) and [`track-by $index`](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/sfgry1ek/42/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was after all rather simple and the resulting code leaner. Doing away with the `v-for` and `track-by $index` directives altogether and using a computed property instead did the trick:

```
computed: {
  currentTweet: function () {
    return this.tweets[this.showing]
  }
}
```

On the html file, it is just a question of adding the computed property `currentTweet` as you normally would, with a mustache tag, here interpreted as [raw html](http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

```
<li>{{{ currentTweet }}}<li>
```

No need therefore for anything like this:

```
<li v-for="tweet in tweets" track-by="$index">{{{ tweet }}}</li>
```

JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/sfgry1ek/46/)