# Display a list when i click next or previous button in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to manage a case in js view. I have a list of employees who arrive in a department and also leave the department. My list returns me 3 objects (entries and exits) for the current week, the next week and the week after.
By default, I display the entries and exits of the current week and I would like with two buttons previous and next to display the other weeks and return to the previous week with the previous button. It's possible to call a watch in `Vue JS`

```
<template>
    <div class="employee-list">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.id">
                <div class="employee">
                    <p class="name">{{ employee.name }}</p>
                    <p class="dept">{{ employee.dept }}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" @click="selectemployee(employee)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" @click="selectemployee(employee)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Next</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            employees: [
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "Marcus",
        "dept": "Informatic Technology",
      },
      {  
        "id": "48",
        "name": "Dimitri",
        "dept": "Marketing",
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
               {
        "id": "36",
        "name": "John",
        "dept": "Businnes",  
      },
      {
        "id": "82",
        "name": "Greg",
        "dept": "Marketing",
      }
               ]
  },
  {
    "inputs": [
               {
        "id": "50",
        "name": "Emilie",
        "dept": "Informatic Technology",
      },
      {
        "id": "15",
        "name": "Julian",
        "dept": "Marketing",
      }
               ],
    "outputs": [
       {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Alan",
        "dept": "Informatic Technology",
      },
      {
        "id": "19",
        "name": "Mireille",
        "dept": "Marketing",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "inputs": [  
               {
        "id": "71",
        "name": "Dupond",
        "dept": "Informatic Technology",
      },
      {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "Dufourd",
        "dept": "Marketing",
      }
               ],
    "outputs": [
       {
        "id": "386",
        "name": "Tata",
        "dept": "Informatic Technology",
      },
      {
        "id": "198",
        "name": "Toto",
        "dept": "Marketing",
      }
    ]
  }
]
        },
        methods: {
            selectemployeePreviousOrNext(employee) {
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.employees-list {
    flex: 2;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-left: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;

        li {
            display: flex;
            padding: 2px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            height: 80px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;

            &.selected {
                background: #dfdfdf;
            }

            span.unread {
                background: #82e0a8;
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                right: 11px;
                top: 20px;
                display: flex;
                font-weight: 700;
                min-width: 20px;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                line-height: 20px;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding: 0 4px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            .employee {
                flex: 3;
                font-size: 10px;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;

                p {
                    margin: 0;

                    &.name {
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it please?

Comment: You can just store visible elements value. By clicking next button store the new visible value. This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387106/vue-js-track-by-index-how-to-render-list-items-individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try like following snippet

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  props: {
    employees: {
      type:Array,
      default: () => [
        {"inputs": [{"id": "38", "name": "Marcus", "dept": "Informatic Technology",}, {"id": "48", "name": "Dimitri", "dept": "Marketing",}], 
        "outputs": [{"id": "36", "name": "John", "dept": "Businnes",}, {"id": "82", "name": "Greg", "dept": "Marketing",}]}, 
        {"inputs": [{"id": "50", "name": "Emilie", "dept": "Informatic Technology",}, {"id": "15", "name": "Julian", "dept": "Marketing",}], 
        "outputs": [{"id": "60", "name": "Alan", "dept": "Informatic Technology",}, {"id": "19", "name": "Mireille", "dept": "Marketing",}]}, 
        {"inputs": [{"id": "71", "name": "Dupond", "dept": "Informatic Technology",}, {"id": "16", "name": "Dufourd", "dept": "Marketing",}], 
        "outputs": [{"id": "386", "name": "Tata", "dept": "Informatic Technology",}, {"id": "198", "name": "Toto", "dept": "Marketing",}]}
      ]
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      week: {id: 0, title: "current week"}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    employeesFilter(w) {
      return this.employees[w]
    },
    selectemployee(w) {
      this.week.id += w
      this.week.id === 0 ? this.week.title = "current week" : this.week.id === 1 ? this.week.title = "next week" : this.week.title = "week after"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.employees-list {
  flex: 2;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
}
.employees-list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.employees-list ul li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.employees-list ul li selected {
  background: #dfdfdf;
}
.employee {
  flex: 3;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
p, ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.employee .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="employee-list">
    <p>{{ week.title }}</p>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(employee, i) in employeesFilter(week.id)" :key="i">
      <p>{{ i }}-{{ employee.length }}</p>
        <ul v-if="employee.length">
          <li v-for="empl in employee" :key="empl.id">
            <div class="employee">
              <p class="name">{{ empl.name }}</p>
              <p class="dept">{{ empl.dept }}</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p v-else>no people this week</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" v-show="week.id > 0" @click="selectemployee(-1)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" v-show="week.id < 2" @click="selectemployee(1)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Nikola Pavicevic yes, that's exactly what I'm going to do. But how to add in the display in addition to the name and dept, the number of inputs and outputs employees a. And if in a week the number is 0 displayed no employee this week.

Comment: @ln3106 hey mate , for number of inputs/outputs just add `{{ employee.length }}` , I updated my answer take a look pls, and your other question I didn't understand :(

Comment: hi @Nikola Pavicevic,The other question is if in the employee object for a week (current or next) the number of employees entered or left is 0 then instead of the name and department "no people this week" should be displayed.
You can add one more week by putting no employees in the entries

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer , pls take a look again, just use `v-if` and `v-else`

Answer (score 0):

Just store the current week index and increase / decrease that index to change the week:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="employee of weekEmployees">
      {{ employee.name}}
    </div>
    <button @click="prevWeek">Prev</button>
    <button @click="nextWeek">Next</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
     return {
        week: 0,
        employees: [], // your array of 3 weeks of employees
     }
  },
  computed: {
    weekEmployees() {
      return this.employees[this.week]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextWeek() {
      if (this.week >= this.employees.length - 1) { return }
      this.week++
    },
    prevWeek() {
      if (this.week <= 0 ) { return }
      this.week--
    }
  }
}
</script>
```